# Network quality indicator on a webapp

Tags: java, javascript, html, networking

Is there a way we could indicate the client's current network quality (a bar of some sort, similar to the n/w quality bar on a phone) on a web application?

A web app of ours, that deals with data transfer, has most transfer failures because of network issues with clients, who obviously don't know about it. Clients keep reporting failures whereas the actual issue is with their n/w connectivity, and I'm looking for a way that can indicate the same (inside my web app) to them when they are using the application.

I know there are other tools for investigating that, but layman user setups don't have them (at least our users).

Thanks.

Comment: I think this would depend on the kind of network interface the client is using.  If it's a physical connection, you're out of luck unless you can figure out how to determine how many packets are being dropped between the client and server.  If it's a wireless connection, then it's going to depend on whether the client's network card has a public API for getting signal strength metrics.

Comment: although im interested in this question in general - i would think you personally would be looking not for some fuzzy quality rating, but rather how to detect and recover from failures caused by network connectivity. i dont see how a "rating" would assist you, other than visibly convincing the user that the software failure is their fault, not yours. even then, a great "100% rating" can have a blip that causes a failure...

Comment: oh yea, absolutely. we are working on improving that experience and recovery mechanisms. but what we want to indicate upfront to the user is that the glitches are expected. Think about how often you look at that phone n/w bar to check if thats the cause for your conversation/voice breaking while speaking!

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use [`window.navigator.onLine`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.onLine) for example:

```
if (navigator.onLine) {
  alert('online')
} else {
  alert('offline');
}
```

or capture the change:

```
window.addEventListener("offline", function(e) {
  alert("offline");
}, false);

window.addEventListener("online", function(e) {
  alert("online");
}, false);
```

You could take averages on certain time intervals and develop an algorithm to quantify the connectivity as 10%, 50%, etc...

You could also just set up an AJAX poll and watch for timeouts, but be careful to not increase traffic too much:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "yourserver.com",
  success: function(data){
    alert("Connection active!")
  }
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    if(textStatus == 'timeout') {
       alert('Connection seems dead!');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: i am looking more at a % indicator, instead of an active/inactive indicator (which we already do), as dynamic as possible.

Comment: Maybe this project could help? [https://github.com/bluesmoon/boomerang/](https://github.com/bluesmoon/boomerang/)

Answer (score 1):

There's some assumptions to make here based on how you transfer data, how much at a time, and how often.

I'll start by assuming you're making XHR requests, because this is really the only way to reliably measure the metrics we need.

As far as how much, I hope you're not sending megabytes at a time.  This makes it harder to measure response time (since network conditions can vary over the life of a large request).  Also, if a user is behind some kind of proxy, oversized requests might get tossed out by the proxy.  Let's assume less than 1 MB.

Finally, if you're only sending data once every 5 minutes, we obviously won't have much performance measurement data to work with.

With that said, I'd approach this by measuring the total request time for each request, and counting the number of failures.  Something like:

```
var recentResults = [], history = 90000;
function sendData() {
    var start = Date.now(); // remember when we started this request
    $.post('/some/api', { some: 'data' }, function(r) {
        recentResults.push({start:start, end:Date.now() - start}); // record how long it took (ms)
    }).fail(function() {
        recentResults.push({start:start, end:null}); // record a failure
    });
}

setInterval(function() {
    var now = Date.now();
    if (recentResults.length > 0) while (now - recentResults[0].start > history) {
        recentResults.shift(); // prune old data
    }


    var sum;
    for (var i = 0, r; i < recentResults.length; r=recentResults[i++]) {
        if (r.end == null) sum += 50000;
        else sum += r.end;
    }

    var movingAverage = sum / recentResults.length;

    // use movingAverage to calculate the overall connection quality

}, 1000);
```

You will have to tweak several of the values I've used here based mostly on trial and error.

- `history` is the length of time (in milliseconds) to keep requests in the moving average.  If you are making frequent requests, you can turn this down.  If you're only making one request per minute, you might need to increase it.
- I've arbitrarily assigned a complete failure as being equivalent to a 50-second response time.  Failures can happen for any number of reasons, including transient network issues (such as poor WiFi signal) and server errors (HTTP 500).  You may want to adjust this based on testing in real-world scenarios.
- I'm sampling the response time data every second.  You can do this more frequently for a more responsive signal meter, but you'll obviously be consuming more CPU cycles to do this.  If your app runs on mobile devices, be very careful.

You'll have to do real-world testing to determine what a 'good' vs 'bad' average response time looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out http://www.igvita.com/2012/04/04/measuring-site-speed-with-navigation-timing/

This gives an idea about new W3c Navigation timing interfaces. Chrome/ffox/IE already has th